# allocate user-space memory from kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, kernel

I'm trying to call

```
sys_readlink(const char __user *path, char __user *buf, int bufsiz)
```

directly, but get EFAULT error code. This error appears because *buf* points to memory from kernel-space.

So, is there possible way to allocate user-space memory from kernel ?

`kmalloc(size, GFP_USER)` is similar to `kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL)`
and returns pointer to kernel memory.

Comment: Why is it you need to do something so high-level in the kernel?

Comment: You're already in kernelspace; you should be calling into the VFS directly instead of using a system call.

Comment: I'm using readlink("/proc/PID/exe") to get full path to the current process image file, is there any other ways to get it ? I can't use  d_path() because it uses one of the system calls, that are already hooked by me, so it returns NULL

Comment: GFP_USER means that it's kernel space memory that you can allow the user to access (typcially used as markers for shared kernel/user pages). Readlink needs a user space virtual memory area and an address in that area. I suggest you take Ignacio's advice or reconsider writing this in the kernel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can temporarily disable memory address validity checking by using `set_fs`

```
mm_segment_t old_fs;

old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
/* Your syscall here */
set_fs(old_fs);
```

Comment: Hi, I had a similar issue. In my case the syscall I want to make is pread. So I called vfs_read directly. I verified that this set_fs(KERNEL_DS) is doing the job. However, later when I opened the file with O_DIRECT flag and do a vfs_read, I am again getting the -EFAULT. Can you shed some light on the O_DIRECT issue?

Comment: @ErbenMo: IIRC `O_DIRECT` comes with some strict alignment requirements (with actual requirements varying between filesystems and kernel versions), this might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: I think the alignment requirements is on the size/address of the data on disk, not the size/address of the buffer that store the data after read... So I am am not sure if thats the problem because the data I am reading on disk is 4kb aligned. It seems the problem is with the in-memory buffer that stores the data.

Comment: @ErbenMo: the requirements are also on the user buffers if I'm not mistaken. Unaligned buffers probably won't work.

Comment: `set_fs` is not relevant for new linux kernels. It is gone now :(

Comment: @EytanNaim: Relevant [LWN article on `set_fs()` removal](https://lwn.net/Articles/832121/) (which was apparently done somewhere in 5.18).