# How to get the file's meta data in kernel space - linux 3.5

Tags: c, linux, file, linux-kernel, metadata

Given a file path, how can I get its meta data. Here is my problem: I have to truly hide a file (even with ls -a it should not show up anywhere) and I donot need to gaurentee that it will have the same state when it comes back. Now I though if  can just copy the meta data and store it somewhere, only to write it back when I need to, It would solve my problem

1. I have to create a copy of that meta data and store it in another place.
2. I have to be able to copy back that meta data when ever I want it to.

So How can I get the meta-data of a file? If there is a better way to fully hide the file how can I?

This is a personal project and I wont have any code up-stream.

I am working in linux kernel 3.5.4v

Comment: Hiding such a way a file probably cannot be done easily and reliably, because the design of the file subsystem is so central to Unix & Linux. However, I don't understand why you can't use temporary files (those still `open`-ed by some user-space processes, but `unlink`-ed).

Comment: What you are doing is nefarious, if not downright evil. I believe you're just learning, not trying to exploit anything nor anyone, but it does not change the fact that the thing you are trying to do has no positive uses, only evil ones (think malware, spyware, worms, viruses). Even though *you* won't try to use the information for such, does not mean *everyone else reading this question* would be as responsible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about the question some more.

There are filesystem-specific ways to create the possibility of truly hidden files, of course, but I'm not at all interested in exploring those. However, there is a different approach, a variant, that might suit your needs.

You could achieve a similar effect by intercepting only the `open` syscall (extending the existing one, to be precise). If the opened file resolves to a nonexisting file, but the directory and the file name match, instead of failing you construct a special path to the "hidden" file, and open that instead.

The existing file would then be a perfectly normal file, just actually somewhere else. Of course, you can put it in a root-only accessible directory (`drwx------ root:root`), and omit the access security check when opening it, to make it "hidden".