# How to allocate user space buffer in kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In some mess up i need to call one kernel function who is not suppose to call from kernel space because in argument it takes buffer from user space allocated.

```
const char __user *buf
```

But i need to call that so how can i allocate user space buffer and pass it with that function arguments.

if possible then i need to do it without any user space interaction.
Is it really possible?

My goal is to call kernel routine from kernel driver who takes arguments     `const char __user *buf`

Comment: Do you actually need the buffer to be in user space, or do you just want to call a kernel routine that doesn't present an interface to in-kernel callers.

Comment: i need to call that kernel routine who takes in args "const char __user *buf"

Comment: If you need to do that you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Which function is it? Maybe someone can suggest an alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [allocate user-space memory from kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629141/allocate-user-space-memory-from-kernel)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be another way, depending on what system call you're actually trying to invoke.

Here is an [article](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/) which explains a little bit about system call mechanics. There is a section which explains how to invoke system calls from kernel space, using kernel memory and avoid the validation.

```
  mm_segment_t fs;

  fs = get_fs();     /* save previous value */
  set_fs (get_ds()); /* use kernel limit */

  /* system calls can be invoked */

  set_fs(fs); /* restore before returning to user space */
```

Comment: OK. I would still prefer that you update your question to describe which system call you're trying to make. Depending on this information, there might be a better way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the usual way to do this is to break the kernel routine in two - an outer routine that deals with system call mechanics, handles the copyin()/coyout() etc., and then calls the inner routine, which does the actual work.

Of course that won't work if you need to have your code self-contained within a module, and don't control the rest of the kernel it's used with.

And in answer to your specific question - I don't know if there's any such API, but I rather doubt it.