# Reading a symbolic link in kernel-space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, symlink

I'm writing a LKM and need to find out where a specific symlink is pointing to. Basically I need the functionality of the syscall `readlinkat` (or `readlink`) but in kernel-space. Is there an easy way to do this?

Using `readlinkat` directly is not working for me, I'm always getting EFAULT (I guess this is because my buffer is obviously in kernel memory space and not in user-space).

Comment: possible duplicate of [allocate user-space memory from kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629141/allocate-user-space-memory-from-kernel)

Comment: Possibly not a duplicate, but might be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you can't use user space system calls(`readlinkat()` or `readlink()`) directly in your kernel module. Rather you need to use exported function / symbol within the kernel space.

Next, may want to look into the [struct inode_operations](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1515) specific to the file system which you are using. Also look into [`generic_readlink()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=generic_readlink) which internally call `vfs_readlink()`.