# Can I allocate memory from the kernel and release it from userspace?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7629857/11108302) that you can read kernel memory if you disable the address validity checks, but that's not what I want to do.

I want to return some strings from the kernel to the userspace, and not being sure of their length I was planning on allocating user memory from the kernel, and then freeing it from userspace when I don't need it anymore, without needing to rely on the kernel again.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I am not very much versed in the innards of the linux kernel, but the only way I can see how this would work is if you make a separate memory mapping for each string. Probably much easier (and faster) to read/write your strings through a file-descriptror

Comment: Allocate the space in the user process, pass the address and size with the kernel call, do copy_to_user from the kernel, free in user space.  That's pretty much how all calls are done.  The kernel should return the space needed so the user can call again with a larger buffer if required.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do, but I'm just curious if there's another way the kernel developers thought of.

Comment: `mmap` allocates memory in the kernel, so you can at least do whatever `mmap` does. You'll have to allocate whole pages. The kernel never allocates less than a page for a program.

Comment: @user253751 Even with `mmap`, the user process still needs to specify a length.

Comment: @IanAbbott actually the length comes from the caller of mmap. If you want to simulate calling mmap from the kernel, your kernel code specifies the length.

Comment: @user253751 Yes I meant the user process that is calling `mmap`. (I don't even want to think about simulating mmap from the kernel, but I think the nearest equivalent is `vmap`.)

Comment: It's possible to do mmap from the kernel and it's fairly easy. Look at the function `vm_mmap()`.